# Error while getting api response Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

## Problem

Once I get a response and try to store it, the object is null and I'm getting this error:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

## Code

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
var value = (JToken)jsonResult.value;
```

## Image

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't help you if we can't see the entire code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try checking if jsonResult != null before attempting (JToken)jsonResult.value

[EDIT]

you can go with var value = (JToken)jsonResult; no need for the .value at the end.

```
        var result = "{ \"id\": \"/apis/574c167dcd7c3216c8c633b3\", \"name\": \"Servicedesk and Operations\", \"description\": \"Servicedesk and Operations Internal API\", \"serviceUrl\": \"dev-endpoint.com\", \"path\": \"test\", \"protocols\": [ \"http\", \"https\" ], \"authenticationSettings\": { \"oAuth2\": null, \"openid\": null }, \"subscriptionKeyParameterNames\": { \"header\": \"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key\", \"query\": \"subscription-key\" } }";
        var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
        var value = (JToken)jsonResult;
        var id = value["id"].ToString();
```

[Extra edit]

or you could go with

```
         var id2 = jsonResult.id;
```

since you have a dynamic there

Comment: json result is not null it has a response in it

Comment: Then show us your whole code, we don't know which part is throwing the exception...

Comment: can you provide as sample json string for testing?

Comment: {{
  "id": "/apis/574c167dcd7c3216c8c633b3",
  "name": "Servicedesk and Operations",
  "description": "Servicedesk and Operations Internal API",
  "serviceUrl": "http://dev-endpoint.com",
  "path": "test",
  "protocols": [
    "http",
    "https"
  ],
  "authenticationSettings": {
    "oAuth2": null,
    "openid": null
  },
  "subscriptionKeyParameterNames": {
    "header": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
    "query": "subscription-key"
  }
}}

Comment: @MalikKashmiri how about adding that to your post and formatting it (Ctrl+K) so we can actually read it?

Comment: @MalikKashmiri updated the answer. tested and it returns the id

Answer (score 1):

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object` occurs when you have a reference a property/method/etc. a particular type should have off of a variable that ends up resolving to null at runtime. In the posted code, there's only two opportunities for that to happen:

1. `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`, where either `response` or `Content` is null.
2. `jsonResult.value`, where `jsonResult` is null.

My guess is that it's actually `Content` that's null, since if there's no body in the response (and there doesn't have to be), then `Content` is not initialized. In general, whenever you have something that could possibly be null, even if you never expect it to be, you should always catch that, by either explicitly checking for a value with an `if` statement:

```
if (foo != null)
{
    ...
}
```

A ternary:

```
var bar = foo != null ? foo.Bar : "default";
```

Or null coalesce:

```
var bar = (foo ?? new Foo()).Bar;
```